# T-SQL All occurrences in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may have been asked and answered before, but I'm having difficulty even phrasing it as a question (hence the title).

I have a databse table with is essentially

```
[EventId] INT,
[FirstOccurance_Month] DATETIME,
[LastOccurance_Month] DATETIME
```

With some data similar to this:

```
[EventId] [FirstOccurance_Month] [LastOccurance_Month]
1         2015-11-01             2016-01-01
2         2015-12-01             2016-03-01
3         2016-02-01             2016-02-01
```

What i'm trying to achieve is a SQL statement that will output the EventId as one column and all of the months it occurred in as a second column. So for the data above it would look like this:

```
[EventId] [Month]
1         2015-11-01
1         2015-12-01
1         2016-01-01
2         2015-12-01
2         2016-01-01
2         2016-02-01
2         2016-03-01
3         2016-02-01
```

I have a feeling its going to involve CROSS APPLY, so i'm heading to find out what that actually is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Tally table for this task:

```
;WITH Tally AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS i
  FROM (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) AS t1(n)
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) AS t2(n)
)
SELECT m.EventId, DATEADD(m, t.i, FirstOccurance_Month) AS [Month]
FROM Tally AS t
INNER JOIN mytable AS m
ON DATEADD(m, t.i, FirstOccurance_Month) <= LastOccurance_Month
ORDER BY m.EventId
```

The Tally table used by the above query contains 25 rows. You can easily adjust it to suit your actual requirement.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e40d9/1)

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, I had an epiphany and came up with a similar solution myself, using information_Schema.Columns as the source of the "Tally" table. Marking this as the answer and will post mine below for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using recursive CTE

```
; with rcte as
(
    select  EventId, [Month] = FirstOccurance_Month
    from    yourtable 

    union all

    select  t.EventId, [Month] = dateadd(month, 1, r.[Month])
    from    rcte r
            inner join yourtable  t on  r.EventId   = t.EventId
    where   r.[Month]   < t.LastOccurance_Month 
)
select  *
from    rcte
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness this is the final solution. I'm still investigating what precisely the accepted answer is doing, it looks better than mine..

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH,-1,(SELECT MIN(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [FirstOccurance_Month]), 0)) FROM LogTable))
DECLARE @endDate  DATETIME = (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, num, firstdate) AS [DateTime] FROM
    (
        SELECT a.[num] FROM
        (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS num 
           FROM BigDataBase.Information_Schema.Columns c
        )a 
        WHERE [num] < 
        (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,@startDate,@endDate) b
        ) 
    ) n 
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT @startDate firstdate
    ) b
) a INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  [EventId],[FirstOccurance_Month],[LastOccurance_Month]
    FROM    LogTable 
) b
ON  a.[DateTime] >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, b.[FirstOccurance_Month]), 0)  
AND a.[DateTime] <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, b.[LastOccurance_Month]), 0)
ORDER BY b.[EventId],a.[DateTime]
```